# SPFieldCurrency GetFieldValueAsText is not returning currency value in correct format

Tags: c#, sharepoint

I have a Sharepoint list with a Currency field Euro (France). The items is the SPList show as:

```
10,000.12 €
9,222.00 €
```

I have the following C# code:

```
CultureInfo ci = new CultureInfo(1036);//fr-FR

string value = SPFieldCurrency.GetFieldValueAsText(doubleValue, ci, ci.LCID, SPNumberFormatTypes.Automatic);
```

The values returned are:

```
10 000,12 €
9 222,00 €
```

First thing that came to my mind was to set the culture's Number Format (ci.CurrencyFormat.CurrencyGroupSeparator for example) to the same as the one in the SharePoint list, but that's where I am stuck. I can't find anyway where I could get the NumberFormat from the SPFieldCurrency field.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should pass the current culture to the method, like this:

```
string value = SPFieldCurrency.GetFieldValueAsText(doubleValue, 
               Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture, ci.LCID,
               SPNumberFormatTypes.Automatic);
```

If you pass the field's culture to this function, it will use the decimal point and thousandth point to format the value. you cannot say it wrong, but just form your perspective.

By the way, the OOB one uses the current culture.